# Understanding of the Hopf-Lax formula

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hamilton-jacobi-equation

This is an exercise in the book *Partial Differential Equations* (2nd edition) by Evans:
[image]

Here $L^*(q)=\max_{y\in {\Bbb R}^n}\{q\cdot y-L(y)\}$ and $L$ is assumed to be such that it is convex and satisfies
$$
\lim_{|y|\to\infty}\frac{L(y)}{|y|}=+\infty.
$$

I played around with the formula for a while but I don't make any progress. I don't see how one could possibly come up with "$DH(Dg)$". I vaguely feel that since $L$ and $H$ are connected to each other by the definition and the first minimum is achieved for some $y$, one might get $DH(Dg)$ by calculating the critical point. Also, a quick search on Google returns the following possibly useful result

[image]

Could anyone give me a hand to see how I shall go on?

Comment: Not sure why "a quick search on Google" was needed - the result you quoted is the previous problem in the textbook, which Evans tells you to use.

Comment: @pizza In the second edition of his book, the hint is deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $y^*$ is a minimizer of the function 
$$y \mapsto tL\left(\frac{x-y}{t}\right)+g(y)$$
then the subdifferential of this function contains $0$. By the chain rule, this implies 
$$
0\in -\partial L\left(\frac{x-y}{t}\right) + Dg(y)
$$
Equivalently, 
$$
Dg \in \partial L\left(\frac{x-y}{t}\right)
$$
by the previous exercise,   which Evans suggests to use (the one you posted at the end of question)
$$
\frac{x-y}{t} \in \partial H\left(Dg\right)
$$
Thus, 
$$
|x-y|\le t \sup |\partial H\left(Dg\right)|
$$
which was to be proved.

Comment: @user147263 I don't see how the chain rule could be applied, since $g$ is only Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: @MathLearner Could it be that the answer's using the chain rule for subdifferentials not derivatives?